# Separating EditTexts

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

in my code I am reading from a database, i am also using a custom adapter to print out each row, in the row there is a texttview, 2 buttons and a edittext. This all works fine but when a button is pressed the edittext is incremented or decremented, is there a way to change my code so that each edittext is separate to the row above or below it? As in when i click a button on one row the edittext will change to two and when i click a button in another row the counter wont carry from the first row to the second.

this is the custom adapter

```
package com.example.rory.dbtest;

/**
 * Created by Rory on 02/11/2014.
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.pinchtapzoom.R;


public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    public int counter = 0;
    private MyAdapterInterface mMyInterface;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, MyAdapterInterface myInterface) {

        super(context, c);
        this.context = context;
        this.mMyInterface = myInterface;
    }
    Context context;


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // when the view will be created for first time,
        // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        return retView;
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // here we are setting our data
        // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views
        TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item1);
        textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

        final EditText edit1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.runningTotal);

        Button plusButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
        plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                edit1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                mMyInterface.updateEditText(counter);
            }
        });

        final Button minusButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
        minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter--;
                edit1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                mMyInterface.updateEditText(counter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is the main activity

```
package com.example.rory.dbtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pinchtapzoom.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyAdapterInterface{

    private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
    public ListView list1;

    com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter db = new com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter(this);
    public MyActivity mMyActivity;


    //public EditText TotalCost;
    //public EditText TotalLitres;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        list1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.data_list);
        db.open();

        mMyActivity = this;

        Button addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, addassignment.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button deleteBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Delete.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button updateBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update);
        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Update.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        try {
            String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/AssignmentDB";
            File f = new File(destPath);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"),
                        new FileOutputStream(destPath));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Log.d("test", "customadapter is " + customAdapter.toString());
                //Log.d("test", "databaseHelper is " + databaseHelper.toString());
                customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this, db.getAllRecords(), mMyActivity);
                list1.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
        });

    }

    public void updateEditText(int value)
    {
        EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        EditText myEditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        myEditText.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        myEditText2.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    private class DBAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        //private ArrayList<>

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            return null;
        }

    }

    public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException {
        //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

And this is my XML row

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="item"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/plusButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/plusButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/runningTotal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/minusButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/minusButton"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/minusButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/minusButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your counter variable is only storing the last value, every time you click the button the new value replaces the old value.

I suggest changing counter from an **int** to an **ArrayList**

```
public ArrayList<Integer> counter;
```

Be sure to initialize the array in the constructor like so:

```
public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, MyAdapterInterface myInterface) {

    super(context, c);
    this.context = context;
    this.mMyInterface = myInterface;
    counter = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //default all counters to 0
    for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
    {
        counter.add(0);
    }
}
```

Change the click listeners to look like this:

```
plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
      private int counterPos;

        public void onClick(View v) {                
            counterPos = counter.get(cursor.getPosition())
            counterPos--;
            counter.set(cursor.getPosition(), counterPos);
            edit1.setText(Integer.toString(counterPos));
            mMyInterface.updateEditText(counterPos);
        }
    });

minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
      private int counterPos;

        public void onClick(View v) {                
            counterPos = counter.get(cursor.getPosition())
            counterPos++;
            counter.set(cursor.getPosition(), counterPos);
            edit1.setText(Integer.toString(counterPos));
            mMyInterface.updateEditText(counterPos);
        }
    });
```

**Explanation**

```
      counterPos = counter.get(cursor.getPosition())
```

cursor.getPosition() will return the current row position in the list. We will use this position number to identify the position in the ArrayList where we store the associated counter value. We get the current value of this counter and store it in the variable counterPos.

```
      counterPos++;
      counter.set(cursor.getPosition(), counterPos);
```

We increment/decrement the value and then set the associated array Position to this new value

```
edit1.setText(Integer.toString(counterPos));
mMyInterface.updateEditText(counterPos);
```

You can then reuse this variable for display purpose as above

This is my first StackOverFlow answer, I hope I have helped! :)

Any troubles just let me know.

Good luck,
Hugh.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply really appreciate it! When i entered in the code above i got an error on the j.add(0) line, i dont know if i am right but i changed the j to counter as this is the array name, but when i ran the code i still had the same problem with the edittexts, should I have kept the variable as j?

Comment: My apologies that was a typo, should be counter.add(0), just updated the answer. What was the problem with the edittexts when you changed this to counter